# How to get all the texts in a range of rectangle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is like this, suppose you are reading a website, i want to get all the texts in all the elements in a range, say rectangle identified by points (100,200) and (500,600). notice that the rectangle might contains part of an element, for example a paragraph

has its content texts spread from (0,0) to (300,300), in this case, only part of the paragraph's texts should be in my returned result.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: Mix AJAX + PhantomJS + Image Cropping tool + OCR tool for an inaccurate, slow, undesirable solution

Comment: There are some similar cases, one solution there is to add a <span> tag for each single word in the html, then each word can be identified by its coordinate, then finally the texts in range can be obtained. This solution is too troublesome, i wonder if there is a better solution.